# Is time in stack overflow XML dump, shown is in UTC or local time?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I downloaded the stack overflow XML dump. I can access the time attribute given in stack overflow as. But my cncern is whether the time shown is in UTC or is local to the time zone of the person who asked the question?

If it is in UTC, is it possible to get to know the local time in which a person has asked the question?

Answer (score 4):

It is in UTC. It is not possible to get the local time of the person who asked the question; to the best of my knowledge, Stack Overflow doesn’t have that information.